# openstack devstack - Unable to stop service using screen

Tags: openstack, gnu-screen, openstack-nova

I need to stop the nova services which is running in openstack devstack.

So as per the previous guidance I have tried using Screen for the same.

Actually I can see that services currently running were getting displayed.

When I try to stop the same by pressing ctrl + C , Nothing is happening , It simply stays in the same screen.
[image]

Anyone please help me out regarding the same.

Have a look at image attached.

Answer (score 0):

I got the way of doing the same:

Actually After listing the services I needed to click enter.

Then it was listing log.

After that I need to press ctrl + C.

So that service is stopped.

Now I can be able to press up arrow and can run the command to start the same.

Answer (score 0):

First find the pid of the task by top command and the kill the task by kill pid_of_the_task